# Determine Item QtyStock after Order using C# and Excel

Tags: c#, excel

How can I cycle trough each order an check if I still have material to make that order?
For example in this image, I want to make an alert when there isn't enough material to produce the order.

[image: Excel File]

I was thinking something like using a double for, but im having a really hard time getting the logic together.
If anyone can help me understand the logic in this problem I would appreciate it

On my Excel file I just used a simple formula (=F3-J3) and (=K3-J4) for the Metal Material.
I want to make an application witch reads the excel file using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and "DataTable". I learned how to read the data and save it on the DataTable, just don't know how to cycle trough the rows and make the subtraction.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a double for loop like I sugested, Im just wondering now if there is a way to optimize the code, or if there are any error, for now its seams to get the job done.

```
 public void Method(){
     for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string partnumber = dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1].Cells["PART NUMBER"].Value.ToString();
            double onhand = double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1].Cells["TOTAL-ON-HAND"].Value.ToString());

            for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {                   
                string part = dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells["Part #"].Value.ToString();
                double BL = double.Parse( dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells["BL"].Value.ToString());

                if(partnumber ==  part)
                {
                    if (onhand >= BL)
                    {
                        onhand = onhand - BL;
                        MessageBox.Show(partnumber.ToString() +": " + onhand.ToString());
                    }
                    else { break; }
                }
            }
          }
```

Note: BL = Customer Order Qty